# In training or on training - differences between British and American English?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, american-english, british-english, transatlantic-differences

I would use "on training" as a short form of "on a training course":

- I'm on training next week.

I would use "in training" (or simply "training") for something that is more long term:

- I'm in training for the London marathon.
- I'm in training to be a nurse.
- I'm training for the London marathon.
- I'm training to be a nurse.

Would you agree?

Are there any differences between British and American English when it comes to "in training" and "on training"?

Comment: I wouldn't normally use either: I'd say "I'm on a course". But if pushed, I think I'd say "in training", but with a different meaning to the idiom "in training", which as you say is a long-term programme. (British English).

Comment: What @Colin said. The preposition ***in*** is [far more common in both AmE and BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+on+training+for%2Cis+in+training+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20on%20training%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20training%20for%3B%2Cc0), but whereas ***on*** is so rare in BrE it doesn't occur often enough to show on the chart there, it does actually occur enough to graph with the AmE corpus. I mainly put that down to the historically greater number of non-native speakers in the US.

Comment: As a British-English speaker I agree that there are circumstances in which I'd use 'on training' as you describe. I think that the reason isn't *just* that it's effectively short for 'on a course' but is also reinforced in a work setting by the use of other phrases like, 'I'm out on business that day', or 'I'll be out on site'. So in a work context, for me, it's short for eg 'I'll be out of the office on a training course'. I might just as easily say 'I'm out on a course' though.

Comment: FWIW, I have never heard *on training* in AmE.

Comment: I'm American, and I can't recall ever hearing (or saying) "on training*, but I think I would understand it if I heard it.  It might even be natural in the context of, "I'm working on Project Q for the next month; what are you on?"   I would say "I'm *in* training," even if it was just for a day — or (perhaps depending on context) "I'm ***taking*** training."

Comment: Yet "on a course" would also be "in a course" in American.

Comment: @developerwjk - I'd say I'd be *at* a training.  I'd be *taking a course*.  (Am. English)

Comment: Interesting!! Thanks for your input. I also prefer "I'm on a course", but there are definitely situations where I would use "on training", e.g., calendar entry or out of office response. I don't think I would ever use "in training" for something like that.

Comment: No, no, no: "in a course" is not AmE. Unless by that is meant something else such as: I'm in a history course, not an anthropology course.

Answer (score 4):

*I'm in training next week* for your status or *I'm at training next week* for your location would be idiomatic to indicate that you are attending, receiving, or taking training classes, in standard English on either side of the pond. Most instances I found of *he is on training* and so on seem to come from non-native speakers.

But there are various contexts— albeit contrived— where *on* could be acceptable to reflect other ways you relate to training. There are rather numerous uses of *[on](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=on)*, after all. For some AHD senses:

> 1f. Used to indicate figurative or abstract position

*on* could be employed if *training* is one item in a list or sequence being done.

*I am rewriting the entire employee manual. I was on travel last week, and I am on training this week.*

If *training* is a work status or role, under

> 8a. Used to indicate the state or process of

you could note *I was out on travel last week, and out on training this week, but I am back on duty the rest of the month*.

> 9. Used to indicate belonging to

*I am on training this week* could mean *I am a member of the training team this week*.

> 13. At the expense of; compliments of

*I am on training this week, because the QA budget ran out.*

These are highly contextual or informal, and can be awkward, but they could explain the appearance of *on training* in various places.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, FumbleFingers wrote:

> The preposition ***in*** is [far more common in both AmE and BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+on+training+for%2Cis+in+training+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20on%20training%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20training%20for%3B%2Cc0), but whereas ***on*** is so rare in BrE it doesn't occur often enough to show on the chart there, it does actually occur enough to graph with the AmE corpus. I mainly put that down to the historically greater number of non-native speakers in the US.